# For high-volume sites like SO, implement a waiting period for first answers

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, new-users

### Problem

Same ones we've heard:

- Difficult for newbies to contribute (upvoted) answers, even when competent in the subject, proficient in English, and a good explainer, due to lack of familiarity with competitive strategies, *e.g.* writing a good *enough* answer first, then editing more details afterward. Even if on par, discouraging for both newbies and experts to have to race rather than teach.
- Racing to be first can decrease answer quality, especially when no edits follow.

### Proposal

**Hold onto any answers submitted in the first few minutes.**

**Then show them all at once (in random order, as usual).**

This gives less experienced users more time to write a well-composed answer that otherwise would permanently be listed second because it was posted 30 seconds behind an expert's. It also gives experts more time to write thoughtful answers instead of racing other experts.

Forces all askers to wait a few minutes for an answer, but only a minute or two more than they'd have to wait anyway...

Comment: They'll learn from our reactions, I don't see a problem actually. Also we give them all of the help they need. Those who don't make themselves  informed before posting anything here are on their own duty.

Comment: But, I don't want them to learn how to be competitive answer-writers. Everyone should want to be _good_ answer-writers. So, my proposals more about fostering that motive, getting more people contribute. I know several programmers personally who see answering questions on SO as if it were speedrunning a game, and understandably have no interest in participating.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - I don't see the relevance of your comment to anything I'm saying... but sure, I agree with your statements as independent facts.

Comment: You know about the [FGITW](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18014/what-is-fgitw-and-scite) problem?

Comment: My only issue with this is it could generate a lot of duplicate answers.  While not a big deal you are could waste a lot of people's time as they still see it as unanswered and so they decide to write a answer even though there is already pending answers.  Then all of the sudden the timeout ends and we have 10 answers that all say the same thing.

Comment: @AndrewCheong See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38981691/1413395) for example. How should that be solved in 1st place? It's the OP's fault primarily.

Comment: @NathanOliver - That's a very good point. At the same time though, the community's mentality would probably adjust. Those who used to urgently click a fresh-on-the-feed question to try to write the first answer, now may choose to forgo that question (knowing too many others would answer it too), and instead try to answer a just-as-new but slightly more involved question he or she has the confidence to "compete" in the waiting period for. Which, I think would be a great thing. But initially, yes, I think duplicates would be abound.

Comment: The FGITW problem is true, but it is mainly related to high traffic tags, duplicated fairly simple questions. I would like more gives us **5 minutes to close it as duplicate**. There is lot of space for new users on SO, low traffic tags, more complex questions etc.

Comment: @AndrewCheong just out of interest what would happen if we close as dupe (or other reason) within the 5 min. waiting period?

Comment: @PetterFriberg - Hm, not sure! I see that as a technical side-effect we'd have to work out, but not a determining factor or whether or not this idea should be implemented. I kind of like your idea of not closing questions (or at least, not showing the count of close votes) for a few minutes (I always had 3 minutes in mind, not 5). Then they can all hit at once.

Comment: @Pekka웃 - Good point. I don't want to argue side-effects here, though. I'm sure there'd be another way to handle it. We're all creative people here. I don't see a priori why a real-time platform can't have some aspects delayed, but I see the side-effects you mean.

Comment: @AndrewCheong this is a great suggestion, I was going to ask something similar but for a different scenario - that being posting a question but quickly realizing you forgot to include an important piece of information either on your own or through someone's comment - so while your editing the question to include more details, people quickly descend like vultures, and begin down voting, and/or posting answers.  Then once the edit is posted you come back to a bunch of irrelevant answers.  So I think your suggestion has merit.  I don't know why people are so against it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Stack Overflow is a real-time platform by nature. No artificial delay is going to change that - and the possibility of getting an answer that may already get the OP on their way within 10 seconds is generally regarded a feature, not a bug.

Either way, by introducing a delay you'd just be moving the problem's goalposts five minutes into the future.

After getting "beaten" by more experienced speed-writers a couple times under the new system (thinking "awesome! I can contribute!" and discovering after 5 minutes that there's 30 other answers, many of them better than theirs because they're written by veterans), newbies will be as disheartened as they are now, if not more.

The solution is to either

- strive to be a good *and fast* writer (which is an awesome skill to develop!)
- or - as many of us do it - train the ability to give an okay quick answer (one that isn't incorrect, even though it may not be a masterpiece) and then constantly improve on it
- ignore the reputation game completely, take all the time you need to write your in-depth contributions, and (I like to believe this is still the case) experience that good-quality content wins the upvote race in the end *most of the time*.

Comment: I wouldn't say "most" people post answers with the intention of immediately going back and editing more into it.  It's honestly a pretty small minority of users that do so, even of active answerers.  It's *certainly* not a requirement to be a good contributor.

Comment: @Servy fair enough, will tone that down

Comment: @Petter I didn't say that - I said "train the ability to give an okay quick answer (one that isn't incorrect, even though it may not be a masterpiece) and then constantly improve on it"

Comment: Hm. I guess, I don't agree. In line with my response to Nathan, I highly doubt there will be 30 answerers once people get used to the system. Answerers will be turned off by easy-to-answer questions that will be (initially) flooded by duplicates, as you say, and diversify to other questions they used to shy away from because they couldn't beat the experts without a waiting period, but now they might. I think it shifts _how_ people answer, and _who_ answers _what_, dramatically. Therefore, I don't see it as merely pushing back the problem 5 minutes. But, you could be right, it may not work.

Comment: In response to your edits: (1) But SO isn't about training people to be a fast writer, why should we force all users to adhere to that standard? I guess it's "good" but... it's like saying we should all just walk to work because it's "good"... (2) That's what I'm against... it serves no purpose on a site about _good_ knowledge. (3) There are so many things wrong with this "solution"... but I think I've spewed enough disagreement for one day :^) Thanks for participating anyhow.

Comment: @Andrew but no one is being forced to adhere to that standard. There are plenty of possibilities for a deep but slow writer to thrive here. The well-researched answer mostly outlasts the shallow ones in the long run. That approach works only for better-than-mediocre questions, though, of course, but that's a *bonus*.

Comment: It took a year, but I revisited this and side more with you than with (past) me (:

Comment: @AndrewCheong I assume that means your answers are being recognized - that's good to hear!

Comment: Haha, not really. I haven't been active. I just had enough of a break to reconsider your arguments from a more neutral stance.

Comment: @AndrewCheong ha, I see! Fair enough!

Answer (score 6):

I'm not unsympathetic towards the idea of ensuring an healthy community growth. However, I don't think that addressing the Fastest Gun In The West behavior is the way forward.

First of all I think questions should be handled as soon as possible, either with a duplicate vote or by an answer. That is after all where we claim to be good at. Keeping the answers in an holding pattern for sometime seems to dismiss that benefit.

Above that the answerers that do care will be influenced by the incoming new answers. They will be triggered to update / improve their answer to guarantee their FGITW lead.  Despite some notorious tags where it all seems to be about the reputation and less so about quality I don't think overall we need to change this as I doubt it will lead to lower quality.

As for potential users that want to participate but are scared off by the rat race: there are different strategies to follow. I personally stay away from the active tab of tags I'm interested in. I do use specific searches to find questions with a certain score, view count or topic. That gives me all the time I need to answer, even if that takes a week. That might not be the biggest reputation boosters but users that are here for the points might not have the interest in helping out in the first place.